# installing .apk file in actual device only for testing

Tags: android, testing, sdk

I want to test my application on actual device, so how can I go for it? And is it accessory to `sign in` and use `zipalign` for this purpose, or they are useful when preparing for publish my application? And is there any way to test my application on actual device without using eclipse?

Comment: how you prepare your application for publish using eclipse or otherway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes u can directly install your application into actual device without signing and zipalign. You can install the drivers for your software into your computer and use you device directly for debugging alternative to Emulator

Refer [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

or you can install using Android adb tool  Refer [Installing an Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move)

or you can directly copy your application package file to you sdcard and install

The easy steps to install your apk using File manager :

1. Copy the APK 
   file you want to install to your phone's memory card.
       And disconnect Phone from USB.
2. Go to Android Market and search and download Astro File Manager.
3. Click on the Install button.
4. After it is installed, open the app (Astro).
5. It will show you your application APK file stored directly in the root directory of your memory card.
6. Just tap on the application you want to install
7. Tap on “Open App Manager”
8. Click Install
9. You are done!

P.S: Don't forget to enable **Unknown sources in Settings > Security**.
And when installing via Eclipse enable **USB Debugging > Developer Options**

Some tips:
http://developer.android.com/distribute/open.html

Answer (score 18):

- download and install [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- [Make usb debugging enabled in your device](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/)
- Connect your device to computer
- go to command prompt and write: "adb devices" this will list all the devices connected
- adb install "path/App.apk"

and you are done. Please note that adb command will run correctly from anywhere if you are having a correct path pointing to android sdk / plateform-tools direcory

I hope this will help you

Comment: To enable USB debugging on newer phones follow the instruction here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

Answer (score 0):

You can install .apk files directly to your android device using the following steps:

- Write click on your .apk file and choose send to -> your device
- You can access it using "Astro File Manager" (downloadable app from play store) also you can click phone menue button
- go to "My Files"
- Select your .apk file to install it.