# How to transfer application from Emulator to Android phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have written an application on Android Emulator which is running well, but how to transfer it from Emulator to Android phone for testing Purpose ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either: 
a) plug the phone in using a USB cable and run the app from eclipse on the phone. This is the best method but you may need to find the correct adb drivers first.
b) copy the .apk file from Project/bin folder to the phone's SD card, locate the file and run to install.
c) Put the .apk file on a http server and locate it through the phones browser, download and install.

Comment: ya,but in 1st case,My phone is not getting detected,Which driver i suppose to install on my computer ??

Comment: Depends on the phone. I find that most of them work if you install the company's software suite. Some phones just don't seem to want to work (with windows anyway). What phone are you trying to use?

Comment: Try installing the latest version of samsung pc studio. This should give you the drivers you need. Otherwise search on google for 'samsung galaxy 3 adb drivers'. Also make sure you have debugging turned on (settings->applications->development)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [recipe in the Android developer web page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you are asking in the comment. Can you give more details? Did you get stuck in a specific step of that web page? Remember that we are not sitting in the next cubicle across the isle [insert Dilbert cubicle farm joke here]. We can't see your screen, so we need a more complete description of what you did, how far your got and what error message you got, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the thread :
[installing .apk file in actual device only for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374407/installing-apk-file-in-actual-device-only-for-testing/5374483#5374483)